# Hastable of hastables, .Add access problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hashtable

I'm trying to re-create an old script that I already have working in `Ruby`, and I'm doing it with C# because I'm migrating a project of mine to Unity.
This Script searches for files inside folders inside 3 different levels. This is what I mean, is a `filepath`, `Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/files_are_here`.

Explanation: My working script (on `Ruby`) performs that by searching every `"Folder1"`, and assigning the name of each one as a Key to a `Hashtable`. (So now I have a `Hashtable` in which every key is the name of a Folder that will represent the `"Folder1"` part of the `filepath` that I mentioned above).
I've also defined as a Value for each of this keys, a new `Hashtable`.

Thereafter, for each `"Folder1"` in my `Hashtable`, it performs a second search for every `"Folder2"` that is inside each `"Folder1"`, and here I add each Folder name of each `"Folder2"`, as a Key for the `Hashtable` of the `"Folder1"` that contains that `"Folder2"`.

For each `"Folder2"` for each `"Folder1"`, I search each `"Folder3"` inside that `"Folder2"` that is inside that `"Folder1"`, etc.

I'm having a problem. I have my main `Hashtable` with every key representing a `"Folder1"`, and I can perform the search for every `"Folder2"` inside every `"Folder1"`.

My problem is when I try to do:

```cs
main_hash[first_folder.Key].Add(folder_2_name, new Hashtable())
```

It says that `('object' does not contain a definition for 'Add')`, but if I:

```cs
Debug.Log(main_hash[first_folder.Key])
```

It prints `System.Collections.Hashtable`, so it is a `Hashtable`, and it should have to have an `.Add()` Method.

What is going on? Anyone knows?. (Even if you tell me to do it other ways so I can improve it, I would love to know why I'm having that error).

Comment: `Hashtable` predates generic types, and can only return the base type `System.Object`. It's up to you to add the code to cast it back to whatever object you believe it to be. See duplicate for more details on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in fact a HashTable, but `main_hash`, which contains it is an object collection. If you're certain that you will always find a hash table in this collection, you can force it to resolve as a hash table with a cast:

```
((HashTable)main_hash[first_folder.Key]).Add(...)
```

otherwise you can take a typed reference and test it:

```
var table = main_hash[first_folder.Key] as HashTable;
if(table != null)
{
    table.Add(...);
}
```